# Geometry Nodes: How to make each polygon of an object into an instance and keep their shape?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Geometry Nodes: How to make each polygon of an object into an instance and keep their shape?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. You can Split Edges to separate them, but I don't think there's a way to batch-convert geometries into individual instances. What is your purpose for that though, maybe there's another way?

Comment: @Kuboå Good point, I was just generally interested if there was an easy way to do this. Fred I. R. generously provided a solution, but it sure seems to be a very manual process, thank you, Fred, for all the hard work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a very repetitive job since geometry nodes as no loops functions but it's possible.
I did it like this:
First you have to set an ID in order to select faces later on.
Set a point on the selection, then you have to delete all the geometry but the selection. But the new geometry keep the same center so if you put it on the new point it will jump, you have to recenter it (Attribute statistic + vector subtract will do the job)
But you have also to move the point to the same location a set position
link to the attribute statistic median will just do that.

[image]

You have your first face as instance in place.
Now you need to select the second, third...
So put in place an iteration system that will select a new point, a new face and so on.
I don't think my iteration system is very great so i don't explain it.

[image]

But it's working... I hope it help.

Sorry for the multiple edit.

**Edit:**

There is a much simpler way to do this using Geometry to instance:

[image]

Then the iteration system is quit the same...

Once again sorry for the edit.

[image]